# How to get transform from object to specific key value pair using lodash?

Tags: arrays, dictionary, lodash, transform

```
Products: [
  {_id: 'xx1', name: 'p1', sku: 's1'},
  {_id: 'xx2', name: 'p2', sku: 's2'},
  {_id: 'xx3', name: 'p3', sku: 's3'}
]
```

I want to replace word '_id' with 'product', and to map to below result:

```
productArray = [ {product: 'xx1'}, {product: 'xx2'}, {product: 'xx3'} ];
```

I tried lodash code something like below but it just doesn't seem to work correctly:

```
let productArray = _.map(Products, '_id');
```

Can anyone help me on this? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would you even need to use lodash? [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencje/Obiekty/Array/map) will easily do the job.

```js
const products = [{
    _id: 'xx1',
    name: 'p1',
    sku: 's1'
  },
  {
    _id: 'xx2',
    name: 'p2',
    sku: 's2'
  },
  {
    _id: 'xx3',
    name: 'p3',
    sku: 's3'
  }
];

const outProducts = products.map(x => {
  return {
    product: x._id
  }
});

console.log(outProducts);
```